# Error being thrown while using DecimalFormat()

Tags: coldfusion

I am using the following code, but i am facing issue where it is showing me the value `$1,099.00` as the value,

Here is the code i am using:

```
#LSCurrencyFormat(DecimalFormat(unitprice),'local','#session.currencylocale#')#
```

With the above code, I get the following error:

```
The value 1,099.00 cannot be converted to a number.
```

I tried wrapping the DecimalFormat() outside but this just gives me a different error.

Comment: Without looking it up, which you can do, my guess is that LSCurrencyFormat expects a number as the first argument.  Since DecimalFormat returns a string, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#LSCurrencyFormat(LSParseNumber(unitprice),'local','#session.currencylocale#')#
```

Or this to just remove commas.

```
#LSCurrencyFormat(Replace(unitprice,",","","ALL"),'local','#session.currencylocale#')#
```

If that doesn't work, you can use this to remove all non-numeric-friendly symbols from a string

```
#LSCurrencyFormat(ReReplace(unitprice,"[^0-9\.\-\+]","","ALL"),'local','#session.currencylocale#')#
```

Edit: Dan is right about decimalformat, and probably right about it being the source of your error (we don't know what #unitprice# itself looks like). When working with numbers, always make sure to store them in the simplest form and only #display# them with decimal formats and the like, if that's your preference.

For instance, if I had users inputting amounts, especially monetary amounts, I'd use one of these to clean out extraneous characters before I inserted the amount into the database.

And for sure, as Leigh points out in comments below, you should always store numbers in the proper data types for your database provider (types like int and money). You should want to store 1099.42 instead of $1,099.42 in the field and in the proper field type.

Comment: As a rule keep your numbers stored and variableized as number (no commas or formatting). Only format them for display at the display level. That seems like what you are trying to do but the error definitely indicates unit price is dollarformatted somewhere along the way. Maybe look for a dollar format function.

Comment: ... and obviously store them *as numbers*. ie The column should have a numeric data type (decimal, money, etcetera) rather than `varchar`.

Comment: @Leigh Yep, I kinda thought that went without saying, but I can appreciate that it's better literally said, especially consdering the context of the question. I'll append it to the answer to make sure Asker reads.